# Transform rows in columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created a Query SQL Server that dismembers my Folders and transforms in rows (delimited by "\")

For example:
My folder is `"N:\TESTEA\subTESTEB"` originally. In my new table, this value is:
an folder name per row.

```
N:

TESTEA

subTESTEB
```

But, I need transform it's rows in columns. Row 1 in Column 1; Row 2 in Column 2; and so on.

Who know any solution for this?
One problem: this folders have multi levels, and not a standard level!

I'm clear?

Below is my SQL Query (I don't know format this SQL code here!):

```
DECLARE @ARRAY VARCHAR(8000), @DELIMITADOR VARCHAR(100), @S VARCHAR(8000),@ARRAYFinal VARCHAR(8000)
select sub_folder_path into #sub_folder_path from GROUP_FOLDER_ACCESS
SELECT @DELIMITADOR = '\'
CREATE TABLE ARRAY(ITEM_ARRAY VARCHAR(8000)) 

WHILE (select COUNT(*) from #sub_folder_path) > 0
BEGIN
SELECT @ARRAY = sub_folder_path from #sub_folder_path ORDER BY sub_folder_path
SET @ARRAYFinal = @ARRAY
SET @ARRAY = @ARRAY + @DELIMITADOR 
WHILE LEN(@ARRAY) > 0
BEGIN
   SELECT @S = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@ARRAY, 1, CHARINDEX(@DELIMITADOR, @ARRAY) - 1))
   INSERT INTO ARRAY (ITEM_ARRAY) VALUES (@S)
   SELECT @ARRAY = SUBSTRING(@ARRAY, CHARINDEX(@DELIMITADOR, @ARRAY) + 1, LEN(@ARRAY))
END
DELETE #sub_folder_path WHERE sub_folder_path = @ARRAYFinal
END
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL 2005 or above, you can use the [PIVOT keyword](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) but it's somehow *complicate*, have a look at [this](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/36399/split-comma-delimited-string-into-separate-columns.html) solution too. I just tried it and it works, although I have to admit that I don't completely understand everything.

Assuming you have a table called "Paths" with a column "Path" where your path strings are in:

```
; with cte1 as (

   select 
     t2.Path,
     t3.split,
     ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t2.Path order by t2.Path) as num
   from
     (
     select *,
     CAST('<X>'+replace(t.Path,'\','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as xmlfilter
     from Paths t
     ) t2
   cross apply
   (
     select col1data.D.value('.','varchar(50)') as split
     from t2.xmlfilter.nodes('X') as col1data(D)) t3
     )


    select Path, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]
from 
(
    select Path, num, split
    from CTE1
) as sourcetable
pivot
(max(split) for num IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])) as pivottable
```

I admit that this is not a fully dynamic version. If you are looking for such a solution you probably have to craete some UDFs for splitting and then use cursors and while loops to fill your data in a previously prepared table.

Answer (score 0):

I have one option for this. you also use pivot for dynamic.

Here is the example please go throw it.

[Dyanamic Pivot](http://dotnetgalactics.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/using-sql-server-20052008-pivot-on-unknown-number-of-columns-dynamic-pivot/)

also look in this

[Five methods converting rows to columns](http://sqlserveradvisor.blogspot.com.au/2009/03/sql-server-convert-rows-to-columns.html)

May be this will help you to achieve you task.